# How can I Base64 UrlEncode a SHA256 Hash of a string in Haskell?

Tags: security, haskell, hash, oauth, base64

This is to create a code challenge and verifier for PKEC OAuth workflows.

The following *seems* like it should work (uses `cryptonite`):

```
import System.Random (newStdGen, randomRs)
import Crypto.Hash (Digest, hash)
import Crypto.Hash.Algorithms (SHA256)

x = do
    gen <- newStdGen
    codeVerifier = C.pack . take 128 $ randomRs ('0', 'z') gen
    codeChallenge = show (hash codeVerifier :: Digest SHA256)
    print codeChallenge
```

But alas, it does not. So I will post the answer I finally solved after much pain and toil.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious `base64url` functions [that Hoogle suggests](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=base64url)?

Comment: that `base64url` is a lens from jose, requiring 2 extra dependencies (that, and I hadn't been aware of it :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer that OAuth workflows expect is... drum roll ~~~

```
import System.Random (newStdGen, randomRs)
import Data.ByteArray.Encoding
import Crypto.Hash.Algorithms
import Crypto.Hash

-- | This is a custom sort of urlEncode that simply replaces bad characters
urlEncode :: String -> String
urlEncode [] = ""
urlEncode ('=':xs) = urlEncode xs
urlEncode ('+':xs) = '-' : urlEncode xs
urlEncode ('/':xs) = '_' : urlEncode xs
urlEncode (x : xs) = x : urlEncode xs

codeVerifier = C.pack . take 128 $ randomRs ('a', 'z') gen
codeChallenge = urlEncode . C.unpack $ (convertToBase Base64 (hashWith SHA256 codeVerifier)  :: ByteString)
```

The problem in the OP code is it base64 encodes a `String`, where as this code waits to convert the hash to a `String`, so you actually base64 encode the hash directly as a `ByteArray`.

Anyways, this kicked my butt, especially since the auth service I was using insisted that my error was `invalid_grant`. It kept effing telling me that I had an `invalid_grant`?! Anyways, I popped a couple gray hairs over this, so figured I'd help the next unfortunate soul.

Comment: Which import was meant to be `qualified as C`?

Comment: @JeremyList I forget what I used there. I think it was just `Data.ByteString` or `Data.ByteString.Lazy`, but the qualifier `C` doesn't make a lot of sense. ByteString should work tho.